# How to multiplex requests for different domains to different servers using Go?

Tags: go

I want to host multiple domains on the same machine, with multiple servers running on the same machine and different ports. I am trying to write a multiplexer which will redirect requests for domain "A" to the server running locally on "portA", and requests for domain "B" to the server running on "portB". How can I route those requests, while making this redirect transparent to the user and search-engine bots?

Currently, I use something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("mydomainA.com", http.RedirectHandler("http://localhost:1234", 302))
    mux.Handle("mydomainB.com", http.RedirectHandler("http://localhost:4567", 302))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux))
}
```

Comment: You want to use `http.ReverseProxy` from the `net/http/httputil` package: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy

Comment: Thanks @JamesO'Doherty. It worked for me. If you are willing to write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

(just posting @james-odoherty's comment as an answer since he hasn't)

You want to use the [httputil.ReverseProxy](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) type from the [net/http/httputil](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/) package.